# Django how to save User Model?

Tags: python, django

Good day again,
so I have a form and a user can add multiple titles. Each submit will create a new object which includes the written title and the user who wrote it(submitted the form).

I tried it with this but I don't know what to add in NewTitle.objects.create(title=title, ...)

\views.py

```
def title_view(request):

    try:
        profile = request.user.newtitle
    except NewTitle.DoesNotExist:
        profile = NewTitle(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTitleForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            NewTitle.objects.create(title=title) #in the () I have to add the user= aswell
            return redirect('/another')
    else:
        form = NewTitleForm(instance=profile)
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form, 'profile': profile})
```

\models.py

```
class NewTitle(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I am working with basic User model. Currently, a user can submit the form and a new object will create just with the given title but without the user who wrote it because I just added title=title and not user=...

Any ideas?

Comment: my older questions with your answers pushed me into the right direction but the problem is still not solved

Comment: A `user` can only have *one* `NewTitle`?

Comment: I dont know, a user should be able to have many title. A new object everytime the user submitted the form. Do I have to use something like manytoone?

Comment: yes, that's a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: But your view seems to suggest that you want to *edit* an existing `NewTitle`, not create a new one? Otherwise it is not clear to me why you construct the form with `instance=profile`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to edit the views.py now it will create a new object with title  + the user?

Comment: Yes, it's measy. I want to create a new one, not overwrite the old one

Comment: I'm not saying it is messy. It is simply not clear for me *what* you want to do? Edit an existing `NewTitle` if there is already one for that user, or each time create a new one?

Comment: each time create a new one :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update an existing `NewTitle` for that user, or create a new one if no such item exists, you can `.save()` the `form`, so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def title_view(request):
    try:
        profile = request.user.newtitle
    except NewTitle.DoesNotExist:
        profile = NewTitle(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTitleForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/another')
    else:
        form = NewTitleForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form, 'profile': profile})
```

You should also unident the `return render(…)` part such that if the form fails, you rerender the form with the error messages.

If you want to create a new one each time, you can not do that with a `OneToOneField`: a `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`: it thus means that the user has *at most* one `NewTitle` object that refers to that user. If you want to be able to construct multiple ones, you thus can work with a `ForeignKey`:

```
from django.conf import settings

class NewTitle(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and then the view looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def title_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTitleForm(request.POST, instance=NewTitle(user=request.user))
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/another')
    else:
        form = NewTitleForm()
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

but then you can of course not fetch the `.newtitle` of a `User` object, since there can be zero, one or multiple ones.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thank you very much!
But python manage.py just brings uns TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: edit: The reason was the decorator. The decorator has to be in the views.py

Comment: @rPi: sorry, I made a typo, that should indeed decorate the view function.

Comment: I checked it out and fixed the one error. The challenge with this code is that you can still only create one title per user. When you try to create a second one, we get "UNIQUE constraint failed: usertest_newtitle.user_id".

Comment: @rPi: did you make migrations and migrated the database? Because for a simple `ForeignKey`, it should not have a uniqness constraint.

Comment: Finally, it works :)
Thank you very much!
I had to delete the database.
Thats annoying but needed.

Comment: How did you learn all this?
I am willing to put in 8 hours per day to learn django but get stuck at mistakes like "you have to delete the database and try it again" ^^

Comment: You can display the titles the user created btw with:

{% for i in titles %}
    <p> {% if i.user == request.user %} {{ i.title }} {% endif %} </p>
{% endfor %}

In the Template

Comment: @rPi: you can also enumerate with `{% for i in request.user.newtitle_set.all %}`, that way you filter at the database side, and not in the template.

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

There steps may help you in getting resolved this issue

1. Reduce the number of gunicorn workers
2. Generally, it is recommended (2 x $num_cores) + 1 as the number of workers to start off with
3. And also Increase RAM from 512 MB to least 2GB (or 1 GB)